# less variables not working with css

Tags: html, css, less

My less variables, for example if I set *h1* color to be *#000*, aren't working, but the rest of the code is.

Here is my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.less?ts=123456789<=filemtime('style.css')?>
```

I tried "stylesheet/less" but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. You need to "compile" the less file in your server (http://lesscss.org/usage/index.html).
2. Add the script who do it in the browser. Read http://lesscss.org/ and search for "Client-side Usage"

Comment: this hasn't helped, its saying i need to use node but when i installed it on the mac it just disappears..

Comment: So, use the client side option add the script to your code, or ask how to solve your problem with the server.